# How to pick a row in a dataframe and make it the columns name? Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image]

I want to make row 3 column index

Comment: Read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to follow the guideline and refine your question to show your effort down such  sample code attempted to solve the problem and error message if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and easy answer is

```
df.T.set_index(3).T
```

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: Nice and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need select row with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) this row from `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Groups'], 'B':['Quantity'], 'C':['Net Sales']}, index=[3])

df.columns = df.loc[3]
df = df.drop(3)

print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Groups, Quantity, Net Sales]
Index: []
```

But better is avoid it e.g. use parameter `skiprows` if use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for get `DataFrame`, main advantage is `read_csv` get right dtypes of all columns:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
J,K,L
Groups Quantity,Net,Sales
4,6,4"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
print (df)
                 A    B      C
0                D    E      F
1                G    H      I
2                J    K      L
3  Groups Quantity  Net  Sales
4                4    6      4

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), skiprows=4)
print (df)
   Groups Quantity  Net  Sales
0                4    6      4
```

**Timings**:

```
In [319]: %timeit (df.T.set_index(3).T.reset_index(drop=True).astype(float).rename_axis(None, 1))
10 loops, best of 3: 43.1 ms per loop

In [320]: %timeit (jez(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 23.7 ms per loop

In [321]: %timeit (jez1(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 13.6 ms per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

Also is added converting to `float` to all solutions, if all data re strings then it is not necessary.

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100000,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df = df.drop([0,1,2])
df.loc[3] = ['Groups', 'Quantity', 'Net Sales']
print (df)

print (df.T.set_index(3).T.reset_index(drop=True).astype(float).rename_axis(None, 1))

def jez(df):
    df.columns = df.loc[3]
    return df.drop(3).reset_index(drop=True).astype(float).rename_axis(None, 1)

def jez1(df):
    arr = df.values
    #get position (number of row) with 3
    idx = df.index.get_loc(3)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.delete(arr, (idx), axis=0).astype(float), columns=arr[idx])
```